# Does Google Maps upload my photos?

Tags: ios, google-maps

Just the other day I got a push notification message that asked if I wanted to upload certain photos I took at a certain place to Google Maps for that place.

It kind of shocked me since I never remember allowing Google Maps access to my photos (must have tapped too quick sometime I guess) and I wonder if they have been uploading my photos like other applications upload your contacts as soon as you allow them access?

They could have analyzed it locally since there's geo information in my images but still the push notification came when I wasn't engaged with the app so that means it came from a server.

I wonder if my images are now in Google's cloud and linked to my account or it was just a suggestion made by analyzing my local data.

Comment: Do you use google photos ? Also, there is no option in settings to deny photos access to maps. So google photos’ data could have been used for the maps service. It is there in their privacy policy.

Comment: No I don't use anything besides Gmail and Search

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370716/how-does-google-maps-know-that-ive-taken-pictures?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does google maps know that I've taken pictures?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370716/how-does-google-maps-know-that-ive-taken-pictures)