# How does google maps know that I've taken pictures?

Tags: iphone, ios, privacy, geolocation, google-maps

Yesterday I've visited a restaurant. The restaurant had a beautiful garden and colorful plants. So I took several pictures there. Today, Google Maps sent me a notification and offered me to share those pictures as I've taken for that restaurant.

How does Google Maps know that I've taken pictures there? Does the app regularly check(while the app is running) my pictures and their location without my knowledge? If so, then Google Maps can also upload those pictures to somewhere without even asking me? **So if I allow access to my photos for an app, does that mean the app can access my photos without showing a "BROWSE" or something like that and upload to somewhere?** I though iOS API needs photos to be picked by user to be shared by an app. Otherwise any app that has proper access permissions **can** access to all of my photos and then may upload all of them to cloud, whithout my knowledge, right?

***Edit***: Ok, I'm having hard time to explain myself. I know if Google Maps has access permissions to photos, then it can access photos. That's not the issue here. The problem is that: My phone is locked and sitting on the table. Then I get a notification from Google Maps, asking to share the photos I've taken yesterday at the restaurant I've visited! Not only that, when I click the notification, Google Maps opens up with a view with already selected photos which all taken at the specified location. This is only possible if I opened the Google Maps app, **after** taking photos, which I did for getting back to home. The problem is, when I open the Google Maps or any other app that has access permission to photos, does this mean all those app **can** access all of my photos, any time(if app is running in foreground)? I thought apps need to call some iOS APIs to show me the thumbnails, then **only the photos I've checked** will be delivered to app. That is, I thought apps can only access the photos I've picked from the thumbnail view and the thumbnail view is mandatory and handled by iOS, just like passcode and touchID(apps can't read users' fingerprint or passcode, it's all handled by iOS).

[image]

[image: Permissions]

Comment: Once you open the flood gates, the app can access your photos without asking again. I'm not sure if there are some restrictions there, but purely from a users perspective, unless you manually disable the permission from IOS preferences, it doesn't need to ask again for the permission to access your photos... That said, I checked Google maps on my phone settings and it doesn't appear to have or want that permission.

Comment: I was thinking there's still a chance that you also have Google photos installed and it automatically backed up the photos to Google, in which case IOS restrictions wouldn't apply. Is there any way these photos could've touched base with Google?

Comment: [does google maps upload my photos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366639/does-google-maps-upload-my-photos) <- this person doesnt use google photos, still gets the notifications. and as said, there's no option to allow/deny access to photos to maps.

Comment: @Joonas I don't have google Photos installed.

Comment: Now that you posted that screenshot I can see that Google maps has read and write access to your photos. So it seems pretty clear that is how it knew.

Comment: This post has some questions which were answered. For the rest, this is the rough draft I've prepared to give you an idea of what kind of question you should ask if you ask a new one. https://pastebin.com/nBk5Tq3b dont elongate this post further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As evident from the screenshot of the Google Maps settings, you've granted the app access to all your photos. So there is nothing which stops Maps from searching geolocations of photos recently taken and make appropriate recommendations.

Also, [this thread](https://support.google.com/maps/thread/4501732?hl=en) here suggests that

> Google Maps suggest automatically to upload photos to places you visited.
> This option could be modified here:
>
> Open Google Maps then go to menu > settings > notifications > your contributions > adding your photos, see suggestions for photos to post (DISABLE THIS BOTTON).

Those who have this or geolocation disabled mayn't see the photos access prompt or access settings..

The best I can speculate is: App has geolocation or location history turned on. When you agree to share/upload photos for *improving the service*, it asks for photos access and it's granted. Now whenever you return from some place to a previously *significant* place, photos can be checked against for location for recommendations.

As per the comment:

> [E]ven if I disable the see suggestions for photos to post option, Google Maps still can access my photos and upload them to anywhere, without showing me a window to pick photos, right?

Would need to see the photos API for that. Till now, what is think is that, it's a native iOS interface to display photos.

Comment: My point is, even if I disable the `see suggestions for photos to post` option, Google Maps still *can* access my photos and upload them to anywhere, without showing me a window to pick photos, right?

Comment: See updates please. And dont use other services for images. Plus the one you used is slow.

Comment: @RamazanPolat Maps has access to your photos including the location information stored there. So next time you use the app it can scan past locations from the geoloc information in the photos, and identify the place(s) you've been.

Comment: @RamazanPolat, here's [Apple's documentation about this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/requesting_authorization_to_access_photos): `After the user grants permission, the system remembers the choice for future use in your app, but the user can change this choice at any time using the Settings app.`

Comment: @Joonas thanks for saving me the trouble.. but older documentations(possibly outdated) provided more details. Do share if you come across. :)

Comment: If this is outdated information, it doesn't matter because he's not developing an app. I don't see apple changing the way this affects the user any time soon. Not in a significant way anyways, unless they suddenly feel like bad PR is the way to go.

Comment: @Joonas, of couse after I grant permission, system remembers it and doesn't ask again. I know that. The problem is, will the app have access to ALL of my photos instantly(without letting me to pick photos)? If this is the case, then any app with proper access permissions can access ALL of my photos so they can upload all of them to cloud without my knowledge, while I am using the app.

Comment: @RamazanPolat, that's what that means. If I ask you for  a key to your house and you give it to me, I don't have to keep asking for a new key to get in until you take it back. If you're worried, you should stop giving it access to you photos. — Yea, apps could be storing the data you give them access to. In the background or when you're using the app or when you're doing a specific action depending on your settings... or not at all if you don't give it permission.

Comment: @Joonas these comments make up for an answer too :) . I cannot take up all this in my post.

Comment: Added some extra info to question, please also consider that part. Thank you. @Joonas.

Comment: @RamazanPolat, I think you may need an app developer to tell you more. I don’t want to give wild guesses on how it works. What I know as a user is that, if you disable Background App Refresh for Google maps and notifications too, it wouldn’t be able to do that. But as long as it has permission to see your photos, it could still check your photos when the app is in the foreground.